# Docker API fails to recognize 'npipe' mount type when creating a container from python

Tags: python, docker, sockets, mount

I am trying to programmatically create a docker container that communicates with a service running on the host machine and listening on a named pipe (a.k.a. unix socket).
I get:
APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "npipe": mount type unknown")

My setup includes:
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
Python 2.7.12 
docker==4.0.1 (from pip freeze)

import

```
docker
from docker.types import Mount

mounts = [
    Mount('/tmp/redis.sock', '/tmp/redis.sock', type='npipe'),
    Mount('/opt/data/', '/tmp'),
]

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run(
    "alpine", 
    **{
        "command":"sleep 600", 
        "network_mode": "host", 
        "mounts": mounts
    }
)
```

Instead of running a 'sleeping' container I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 803, in run
    detach=detach, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 861, in create
    resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 429, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 440, in create_container_from_config
    return self._result(res, True)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/opt/grok/ve/grok/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "npipe": mount type unknown")
```

Any ideas what is happening?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue. It's poorly documented, but it looks like `npipe` mounts are Windows-specific. I guess on Linux and macOS you're just supposed to create your own and bind-mount it as with any other file.

- https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/f620349837ce/docs/reference/commandline/service_create.md#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems

  > npipe: mounts named pipe from the host into the container (Windows
  >   containers only).
- https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/1dd20ae/components/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/api/types/mount/mount.go#L18-L19

  > TypeNamedPipe is the type for mounting Windows named pipes